# Django syncdb tries to delete table that does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql-9.3, django-syncdb

I am running `syncdb`. Django finds a content type where I have deleted the corresponding table already:

```
The following content types are stale and need to be deleted:

    installs | socialdata
```

After answering 'yes' to continue, Django tries to delete a table `tagging_taggeditem` that's been removed ages ago.

I have checked the `django_content_type` table, but it has no entry pointing to that old table.

**Any ideas?**

(django 1.6)

Comment: Do you still have the tagging app installed?

Comment: There is no tagging app at all anymore.

Comment: Sorry I cannot think of why Django would continue ot have reference's to these models then. Have you done a grep/ack/grin of your codebase for any possible matching models?

Comment: Yes, and I have deleted old .pyc files as well.

Comment: Yeah I'm not really sure tbqh; you're going to have to provide some further information. This is probably going to get closed as Off-Topic: Debugging. Sorry I can't help any further :)

Answer (score 1):

```
pip freeze | grep tagging
django-tagging==0.3.1
```

and I found a file that still had an old import:

```
from tagging import models as taggingmodels
```

After removing that `syncdb` runs fine.